# Stateful vs stateless architecture for web server

Tags: mysql, tomcat

I am building a server that will support web apps and mobile apps.

Should I use stateless or stateful server, and what is a good sample architecture?

The rest of this information is to give you an idea of what I want to support:

Currently I have a MySQL with 400,000+ entries in a certain row and growing.

Here is what I need to do:

1. A client will send the name of a car part to the server.
2. The server queries MySQL (by using JOIN) to find all cars with that car part. It returns an array.

(Here is the tricky part)

3. The server needs to hold on to these results and wait for another request. Repeat as many times as the user wants.
4. Once all car parts have been queried then there will be many arrays of parts held by the server. It will then find the cara with the most parts, and only send those back to the client (using JSON)

Example:
Query 1: Brand ace steering wheel --> result (array of 1000 cars)

Query 2: Brand race bucket seat --> result (array of 2000 cars)

Query 3: Brand bose speakers --> result (array of 400 cars)

Now we compute a match:
Car 1 has 2/3 parts queried, car 2 has 1/3, car 3 has 3/3, etc for the 3400 results.

The user specified a 60%+ match so only car 1 and 3 are sent back.

Additionally I think I can make a hashmap that will do this in constant time and keep it in memory so that each request is routed to the map.

Sample hashmap:
Key || Bose speakers --> value || (array of cars with bose)

Based on this, which state should I use, and what kind of architecture?

Comment: That question would get better answers in stackoverflow. Serverfault is aimed at server and network administration, not web application development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use Stateless application design if you possibly can.

Have a read of [Roy Fielding's dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm) about RESTful applications.

There's lots of reasons to use REST, and not a lot not to.    It makes load-balancing immensely easier, and gives you a considerable benefit when it comes to scaling out, rather than scaling up.

You can use callbacks to get the asynchronous flow you want for your application.

Comment: Will read it thank you. What about keeping the data structures in memory? (Hashmaps, array, etc) to speed up queries. How can I do that if it is stateless

Comment: You use Memcached.